# Implementing a GloVe embedding layer into Keras model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, embedding

I am looking at creating a siamese network in which the format of the code I am using follows the keras Model instantiation seen here [Keras API](https://keras.io/models/model/)

I am having trouble trying to implement an Embedding layer into this as everything I have found only applies an embedding layer to a sequential model as seen here [sequential](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/#embedding), is there any way to do it following the Model version taking inputs and outputs? I have tried first creating an embedding layer and then adding it to a dense layer after but it gives me errors saying it is not valid code (in python).

```
e = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=4, trainable=False)
input = Input(shape=(input_dimen,))

em = Embedding(e)(input)
dens = Dense(128)(em)
batch = BatchNormalization()(dens)
relu = Activation('relu')(batch)
```

This is my code, the error returned states that I am not feeding tensors to the model. 'Input tensors to a model must be Keras tensors'

Comment: Could you add what you have tried along with the error traceback?

Comment: just added an update